# Can't kill Mongodb server from outside the running terminal

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Beginner alert! I'm using express.js with mongodb and I set up a mongodb server in a terminal window through

```
mongod -dbpath *path name*
```

I accidentally closed the text editor without killing the terminal window that had the server running, so when I tried to set up a new server somewhere else it said that there was already a server running and wouldn't let me start another. I can't figure out how to close the last server because I can't go back to the terminal that it was running from and kill the terminal with control+c.
Is there a way to kill all mongodb servers from outside the terminal window that it's running?

Comment: mongod --shutdown

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

```
mongod --dbpath /path/to/your/db --shutdown
```

You can follow this official page for more info -

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/